# Inherited-field vs init-field

Tags: inheritance, scheme, racket

I'm working on a project and I already have some working procedures but I'm having trouble with the initialization variables of one of them.

```
(define red-de-flujo%
  (class grafo%
    (init-field nodof nodod)
    (inherit-field N A)

    (super-make-object)
    (let ([Ninfo (map (λ (n) (send n get-info)) N)])
    (cond
      ((or (not (in? (send nodof get-info) Ninfo)) (not (in? (send nodod get-info) Ninfo))) (error "nodos fuera de N"))
      (else (void))
      )
      )
    (inherit get-nodos get-aristas)
    (define/public (get-nodo-fuente) nodof)
    (define/public (get-nodo-destino) nodod)
    )
  )
```

This piece of code works, however I use another method to `make-object`s of type `red-de-flujo%`. Here's that piece of code:

```
(define/public
      (crear-red-de-flujo N A nf nd)
      (make-object red-de-flujo% nf nd N A ) <<-- not as in definition
      )
```

The thing is that a flow network (red-de-flujo%) is defined by a set of nodes, a set of edges and 2 separated nodes.

My question is: is there a way to put inherited fields above init-fields? The way my `red-de-flujo%` is written (using inheritance) forces me to send init-fields first and inherited-fields last. I'd like to be able to do something like: `(make-object red-de-flujo% N A nf nd)` without losing inheritance.

I already tried changing the order of statements in the code but it's the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can change the inherited initialization argument order for `make-object`, but you can work around this by just using named initialization arguments (via [`new`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/objcreation.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fclass-internal..rkt%29._new%29%29) or [`instantiate`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/objcreation.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fclass-internal..rkt%29._instantiate%29%29)) instead to get whatever order that you want:

```
(new red-de-flujo% [N N0] [A A0] [nf nf0] [nd nd0])
```

where `N0`, `A0`, etc. are just placeholders I put for the actual values you want to pass in.

(Note: I originally had a longer explanation here, but I think it was wrong so I've deleted it)

Comment: This is how I used to have my code earlier, I changed it because I thought it looket better with make-object. Thanks!